# Strange issue relating to shell script files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have this shell script inside a file called *restart_server.sh*:

```
echo "KILLING SERVER SESSION"
kill $(cat serverlastpid.txt)
sleep 20
echo "STARTING SERVER..."
java -jar eu.greensmartcampus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar </dev/null>/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $! > serverlastpid.txt
echo "SERVER STARTED! PID:" $(cat serverlastpid.txt)
```

If I execute each line individually I get this:

```
root@production:/opt/AppServer# echo "KILLING SERVER SESSION"
KILLING SERVER SESSION
root@production:/opt/AppServer# kill $(cat serverlastpid.txt)
root@production:/opt/AppServer# sleep 20
root@production:/opt/AppServer# echo "STARTING SERVER..."
STARTING SERVER...
root@production:/opt/AppServer# java -jar eu.greensmartcampus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar </dev/null>/dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 14620
root@production:/opt/AppServer# echo $! > serverlastpid.txt
root@production:/opt/AppServer# echo "SERVER STARTED! PID:" $(cat serverlastpid.txt)
SERVER STARTED! PID: 14620
root@production:/opt/AppServer#
```

Now, if I just run all these lines inside a shell script file, I get this output instead:

```
root@production:/opt/AppServer# sh restart_server.sh
restart_server.sh: 1: restart_server.sh: echo: not found
STARTING SERVER...
SERVER STARTED! PID: 14777
[1]+  Exit 143                java -jar eu.greensmartcampus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
root@production:/opt/AppServer#
```

Some *echo* messages are missing and some errors appear on the screen.

Why does this happen? What differs from running each line individually or running in a .sh file?

**EDIT:** Adding #!/bin/bash as the first line outputs:

```
root@production:/opt/AppServer# sh restart_server.sh
restart_server.sh: 1: restart_server.sh: #!/bin/bash: not found
KILLING SERVER SESSION
STARTING SERVER...
SERVER STARTED! PID: 15366
root@production:/opt/AppServer#
```

Comment: What is the first line of your script? What shell are you using?

Comment: bash I guess. The first line is *echo "KILLING SERVER SESSION"*

Comment: Consider making the first line **#!/bin/bash**...

Comment: He keeps complaining about the first line, which is now #!/bin/bash. (Check my edit in the OP because comments cannot have line breaks).

Comment: Ugh. What os is this? I haven't come across a single Linux distribution that doesn't have /bin/bash in about twenty years....

Comment: Linux production 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2 x86_64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70480/discussion-between-tink-and-pedrod).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70480/discussion-between-tink-and-pedrod).

The problem turned out to be a Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) encoded in UTF-8 as bytes 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF, which the shells didn't like.  Removing that, and ensuring that the shell code will work with `dash` rather than `bash`, got things working correctly.

Key steps in the diagnosis were:

- Establishing that the shell is `dash` not `bash`.
- Using a hex dump tool to inspect the first few lines of the file so the BOM was visible.
- Knowing how to get rid of the BOM (which was conveniently followed by a newline, so `sed` could be used easily).
- Using `sh -x restart_server.sh` to see what was being executed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call bash in order to execute a bash script, to do that use

```
whereis bash
```

then you should put in the **first line** of the bash script the given path

i.e. `#!/bin/bash`

sometimes it is `#!/bin/sh`

it depends on your distro